# How to add gperf to windows 7 classpath (and have it recognized in DOS)

Tags: windows, classpath, titanium, gperf

I'm trying to add GPERF to my classpath in order to build some Titanium 1.8+ modules. I've installed GPERF from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net and assigned the path to my CLASSPATH and PATH variables, but eclipse / dos isn't picking it up. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't support DOS. Are you *really* using DOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out by dropping the gperf.exe into the System32 folder. Not sure why that worked but putting it on my classpath didn't...